# SQL Server: Express or Commercial

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I need to develop an application that's going to be used by around 30 users across various locations. Is SQL Express sufficient, or would I need to look into a commercial license? Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about licensing are off-topic as found in this question:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365262/microsoft-sql-server-licensing

Comment: This article compares all (most) features between editions: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993%28v=sql.120%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Express edition isn't limited by number of users. What's more important is the potential size of your DB. SQL Express limits the DB size to 10GB (I think). So if you think your DB will grow bigger than this, Express won't be the right choice. Also, I believe Express is limited to 1GB of RAM (which isn't much).